# Java Cucumber storing value returned by step

Tags: java, testing, cucumber

i'm writing a cucumber test and i come up with some difficulty:

I have a step which creates dto and saves it using save client which returns dto back again i would need to use that returned dto for other step but don't know how to make it.

Here's how it looks in code :

**commonExpenseCreationSteps.java**

```
@Given("^new \"([^\"]*)\" expense with type \"([^"]*)\"$")
public ExpenseDTO newExpense(String description, String expenseType) throws Throwable {
    ExpenseDTO expenseDTO = new ExpenseDTO();
    expenseDTO.setDefaultPurpose(description);
    expenseDTO.setExpenseType(expenseType);
    return expenseSaveClient.save(expenseDTO);
}
```

**expenseTransactionsSendSteps.java**

```
@Given("^send expense for Approval$")
public void sendExpenseForApproval() throws InterruptedException {
    expenseTransactionSendClient.sendToApproval(expenseDTO);
}
```

How it would be possible to store value returned by one Step and use it in other one in this case i return ExpenseDTO in newExpense method but i need to use it in sendExpenseForApproval but don't know how to do it !?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34449948/how-to-pass-variable-values-between-steps-in-cucumber-java
check this out

Answer (score 0):

Create expenseDTO object outside of your glue code, probably in your stepdef class constructor.

```
ExpenseDTO expenseDTO = new ExpenseDTO();
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to share state between steps in the same class is to use instance variables. Set the value in one step and use that value in a later step.

The way to share state between steps with two or more step classes is to use dependency injection.

I wrote a [blog post](http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2017/04/01/sharing-state-between-steps-in-cucumberjvm-using-picocontainer) that describes how it can be done using PicoContainer.