# Cannot Pass Instance Variables Within QAFTestStepProvider Class

Tags: java, bdd, cucumber-jvm, qaf

I get a NullPointerException for instance variables that are instantiated in a method with a @Given annotation as shown in the code below for "test":

```
import com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.QAFTestStepProvider;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;

@QAFTestStepProvider
public class Steps
{
    String test;

    @Given("^Step 1$")
    public void step1()
    {
        test = "test_string";
    }

    @Then("^Step 2$")
    public void step2()
    {
        String[] list = test.split("_");
    }
}
```

I've seen various examples([second to last code example](http://testerstories.com/2015/10/page-objects-with-selenium-and-cucumber-jvm/)) and resources([first paragraph of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26434468)) that say this should be fine, as DI would only be necessary when attempting to share states between Step Definition Java classes, not within a class itself.

Is there something I am missing or is there a way to make this work?

Comment: which version of qaf you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [qaf-release-notes-2.1.9](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/release_notes.html#ver-219-release-notes) you need to set `step.provider.sharedinstance` to `true` (default value is `false`). In application properties you can specify

`step.provider.sharedinstance=true`