# Cucumber, java - How can I use return value in the next step?

Tags: java, cucumber

I can't use returned value in the next steps.
Exaple:
I have a method:

```
public class learn_BDD {



    @Test
    @When("^ I have \"([^\"]*)\" dolars on acount$")
    public String checkAcount(String amount){

        String Value = Acount.checkValueOfAcount();

                return returnValue;
    }
    @Test
    @Then("^Check how much I spend$")
    public void howMuchISpend(String returnValue){


        String actualValue = Acount.actualAcountState();
        if (actualValue < returnValue) {
            System.out.println("You are spend money");
        }
    }
```

In this case I give than error:

`***BDD is declared with 1 parameters. However, the gherkin step has 0 arguments [].***`

If somebody can help me I will be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing is due to a lack of a capture group in the regular expression provided to the `Then` annotation.

The `howMuchISpend` method has 1 argument so Cucumber expects 1 capture group, for example, `@Then("^Check how much (.+) I spend$")`. The string captured by `(.+)` is passed as the value of its argument.

```
@Test
@Then("^Check how much (.+) I spend$")
public void howMuchISpend(String returnValue){


    String actualValue = Acount.actualAcountState();
    if (actualValue < returnValue) {
        System.out.println("You are spend money");
    }
}
```

Regarding the other part of your question, each step definition is independent, the value returned by a test method is ignored. If you want to pass values from one step to another you have to use a class scoped variable.

BTW, making steps dependent should be avoided.

Comment: Thanks for answer.


Can You write one example with use a class scoped variable?
I will by grateful.

Comment: @Justi1991 You can see a more detailed example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43067617/cucumber-java-how-to-use-returned-string-from-a-step-in-next-step

Comment: Thanks for your time